# How to pass comma separated values to LINQ query without for loop

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

I have list of values separated by commas, I need to pass these values to LINQ query and get matching values from DB, I have used for loop to solve this problem

here is my code

```
string drawingList="a,b,c,d";
string[] drawings = drawingList.Trim(',').Split(',');
IQueryable<table> filteredItems = null;
filteredItems =(some linq query)
List<table> filteredResult = new List<table>();
for (int i = 0; i < drawings.Count(); i++)
{
    dr = drawings[i].Trim();
    filteredItems = filteredItems.Where(p1 => p1.WorkItemNumber.Equals(dr));
                    filteredResult.AddRange(filteredItems);
}
```

How can I solve the above problem without the for loop

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
filteredItems = filteredItems.Where(i => drawings.Contains(i => i.WorkItemNumber));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var result = from   drUntrimmed in drawings
               let  dr = drUntrimmed.Trim()
             from   f in filteredItems
             where  f.WorkItemNumber.Equals(dr)
             select f;
```